# Request for Tag Merge: pcie and pci-express

Tags: support, status-completed

[pci-express](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pci-express) has a description, and [pcie](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/pcie) doesn't, it seems like pcie should be merged into pci-express. Unless there's some difference between those two phrases that I'm not aware of.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All done